# Newbie Issues with Solving & Plotting a System of equations

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, system-variables

I'm having some problems with my mathematica code, I think I'm overlooking something simple. I get valid solutions for u0 thru u4, but it doesnt generate any plot at all. Also, I'd really like to plot in terms of ph, not ohc, and have given the relationships as well.

```
Solve[{u0 + u1 + u2 + u4 == 1,
  k1 == u1/(u0*ohc),
  k2 == u2/(u0*ohc^2),
  k4 == u4/(u0*ohc^4)},
 {u0, u1, u2, u4}]

Solve[Log[10, k1] == 9.5, k1]
Solve[Log[10, k2] == 22.8, k2]
Solve[Log[10, k4] == 32.4, k4]

ph == 14 - poh;
poh == -log[ohc];

Plot[{u0, u1, u2, u4}, {ohc, 0, 1}]

*Preferred:* Plot[eqns,{ph,0,14}]
```

Comment: Look up `/.`: `{u0, u1, u2, u4} /. Solve[(* equations *), {u0, u1, u2, u4}]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I've tried defining Sol = Solve[...] and  using the /. after the {u0-u4} but it still wont plot

Comment: `sol = Solve[{u0 + u1 + u2 + u4 == 1,
   k1 == u1/(u0*ohc),
   k2 == u2/(u0*ohc^2),
   k4 == u4/(u0*ohc^4)},
  {u0, u1, u2, u4}]`:
`Solve[Log[10, k1] == 9.5, k1]
Solve[Log[10, k2] == 22.8, k2]
Solve[Log[10, k4] == 32.4, k4]
`:
`Plot[{u0, u1, u2, u4} /. sol, {ohc, 0, 1}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ph == 14 - poh;
poh == -log[ohc];
```

These are equalities, not assignments. Your `Solve` function is written correctly, but the result needs to be assigned to something like

```
sol = First@Solve[
  {
    u0 + u1 + u2 + u4 == 1,
    k1 == u1/(u0*ohc), 
    k2 == u2/(u0*ohc^2),
    k4 == u4/(u0*ohc^4)
  },
  {u0, u1, u2, u4}];
```

To plot this solution with your values of `k1`, `k2` and `k4` use `/.`

```
Plot[
  Evaluate[
    {u0, u1, u2, u4} /. sol /. {k1 -> 10^9.5, k2 -> 10^22.8, k4 -> 10^32.4}
  ],
{ohc, 0, 10^-4}]
```

[image: sol wrt. ohc]

where I have limited your range of ohc to make the function visible. To plot wrt. `ph` instead, we can solve your expression

```
phsol = First@Solve[ph == 14 + Log[ohc], ohc, Reals]
```

and substitute this into the plot function as well

```
Plot[
  Evaluate[
    {u0, u1, u2, u4} /. sol /. phsol /. {k1 -> 10^9.5, k2 -> 10^22.8, k4 -> 10^32.4}
  ],
{ohc, 0, 10}]
```

[image: sol wrt. ph]

Note that in both cases, the scale of u0 and u1 is several orders of magnitude different from your other variables. You can rescale them using

```
Plot[
  Evaluate[
    {10^10 u0, 10^7 u1, u2, u4} /. sol /. phsol /. {k1 -> 10^9.5, k2 -> 10^22.8, k4 -> 10^32.4}
  ],
{ohc, 0, 10}]
```

[image: sol wrt. ph with scaling u0 and u1]

Comment: wow you are a god amongst men. May I ask what the First@ and evaluate do in their context? This was a great example of how the /. operator works. I was also missing the "Reals" piece and I think that was what was messing me up in solving for ohc. Thanks!

Comment: Congratulations on your first `Godhood` badge!

Comment: They are just for neatness. The output of Solve is nested in two `{{...}}`. Doing `First` (or `Last`) gets rid of the outer `{...}`

`Evaluate` is there to get past a funny nuance of plotting lists of variables in this way. Try removing it, and you will see the lines no longer have different `PlotStyle`

Comment: Good tips again

Comment: also, is there a way to convert a number such a 5.6*10^-23 to base 10 in mathematica?

Comment: I think you mean something different from what you said, but I'm not sure what. Try rephrasing?

Comment: oh never mind, thats just using the log equation. I just realized that the logs I'm using are actually base 10, so it switches up the graphs and they make more sense now.